# Does my laptop supports m.2 nvme ssd?

Tags: ssd, nvme, m.2

I have a asus vivobook r542uf laptop.Does it supports nvme ssd? I’ve searched the specs but no info about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your [laptop specifications page](https://www.asus.com/lk/Commercial-Laptops/R542UF/specifications/) lists

> #### Storage
>
> ##### Hard drive:
>
> - 500GB 5400 rpm SATA HDD
> - 1TB 5400 rpm SATA HDD
>
> ##### Solid state drive:
>
> - 128GB SATA 3.0 M.2 SSD
>
> ##### Solid state drive:
>
> - 256GB SATA 3.0 M.2 SSD

It does not list NVME at all so you are probably limited to SATA M.2 SSDs.